# Replace values in struct before saving

Tags: ios, swift

I add new empty cell on last row (with placeholders) by clicking on button and I don't want to save empty Strings to firebase database

So I want to replace data from placeholders to entered text before saving it in firestore database, but I don't how to change " " to new text which user wrote.

```
var models: [DataCell] = []
...
...

 @IBAction func nextExcerciseButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: models.count - 1, section: 0)
    
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! NextExerciseCell
    
    var exercise = cell.newExercise.text
    exercise = ""
    
    var kg = cell.newKG.text
    kg = ""
    
    var sets = cell.newSets.text
    sets = ""
    
    var reps = cell.newReps.text
    reps = ""

    let newData = DataCell(Number: "\(models.count - 1)", Exercise: exercise! ,kg: kg!, sets: sets!, reps: reps!, workoutName: "\(titleValue)")
    
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    models.append(newData)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: models.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    tableView.endUpdates()
   
    unhideButton()
        
}

func unhideButton() {
    tableView.reloadData()
    let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: models.count - 1, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! NextExerciseCell
    cell.checkBoxButton.isHidden = false
        cell.index = indexPath
        cell.cellDelegate = self
        
   
}

    
func saveNewCell(indexPath: IndexPath) {
   
    if let newNumber = String(models.count) as String? , let newExercise = models[indexPath.row].Exercise as String?, let newSets = models[indexPath.row].sets as String?, let newReps = models[indexPath.row].reps as String?, let newKg = models[indexPath.row].kg as String?  {
    
                db.collection("users").document("\(user!.uid)").collection("WorkoutsName").document("\(titleValue)").collection("Exercises").document().setData(["Number": newNumber, "Exercise": newExercise, "Reps" : newReps, "Sets" : newSets, "kg" : newKg, "workoutName": titleValue], merge: true, completion: { (error) in
                        if let e = error {
                            print("There was an issue saving data to firestore, \(e)")
                        } else {
                            print("Succesfully saved data.")
                        }
                    })
            }
    }
```

Comment: Where does the user enter the new text? Directly in the cell? Why do you bother fetching the last cell?  You can just add a new element to your array. Also, why are numeric values, like kg and reps stored as strings?  A more common UI/UX would be for the "add" button to show a modal dialog that gathers the required information and add it to the array rather than having empty data in your array

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last element before saving:

```
let toSaveModels = models.prefix(models.count-1)
```

Or:

```
models.removeLast()
```